# Django static files разница в работе локально и в сети

Tags: html, django, python-3.6, static

world!
У меня вопрос уровня новичка. Дело такое:
Решил на django 3.2.12 написать маленький website. Создал проект, приложение и html. В настройках settings.py указал все необходимые данные, включая выгрузку с папки static. В саму папку static поставил картинку.
Если запускать все локально (127.0.0.1), все работает как "Кока-Кола", но если выгрузить в сеть, то сервер не находит картинку. Я долго мучился и только потом вспомнил про функцию collectstatic. И картинка высветилась.
Вопрос следующий:
Это что получается, что при каждом пользователе выложивший свое изображение на website'e я буду обязан выполнять collectstatic??? Можно обойтись без этого?
Выгрузка изображения происходит не в models.py, а самым обычным способом:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML LANG="en">
{% load static %}
<head>
</head>

<body>
<img src={% static "fdog.jpg" %}>
</body>
```

Я тут посидел и подумал. Понял, что я написал глупость. Когда пользователь выкладывает изображение оно не "вшивается" в шаблон, а содержится где-то и выгружается с помощью models. Логично. Также можно через js.
Ок, перезадам вопрос:
Для чего нужно collectstatic и почему локально изображения выкладываются без него, а на сервере он необходим? И можно ли обойтись без него?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Пользовательские картинки должны лежать не в static, а в media. Настройте MEDIA_ROOT и MEDIA_URL (они должны быть полностью отдельно от static), настройте веб-сервер на раздачу файлов из папки MEDIA_ROOT и всё будет хорошо без всяких collectstatic

Comment: И не используйте `{% static %}` для пользовательских файлов, он предназначен только для собственных файлов проекта

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том что в производстве django не обслуживает ваши статические файлы, это выполняет ваш вэб-сервер(**apche**, **nginx** и т.д)
Вам необходимо указать вашему вэб-серверу где находятся статические файлы.
Также вам необходимо указать `STATIC_ROOT` в место `STATICFILES_DIRS`, подробней о статике [тут](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/deployment/#:%7E:text=Serving%20static%20files%20in%20production,static%20file%20server%20and%20served.)

Comment: Для собственных файлов проекта это всё хорошо и правильно, но пользовательские файлы вообще не должны лежать в STATIC_ROOT, для них есть MEDIA_ROOT

Comment: Если же картинка была загружена с сайта то да, однако если это, статический файл который участвует  лишь в дизайне и помещен туда для этого, то это уже статика.